# Object pointer array returns one more value?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

So I have this pointer array that points to a maximum of 4 objects of the same base class.

```
private:
    Instance* paths[3];
```

I assign a pointer to a slot of the array if there is an object I want to point to. And NULL if there's nothing to point to.

I have this set function to do that:

```
void Instance::setNearbyObjects(Instance* north,Instance* east,Instance* south,Instance* west)
{
    paths[0]=north;
    paths[1]=east;
    paths[2]=south;
    paths[3]=west;
}
```

I also have this get function that just returns the paths array:

```
Instance* Instance::getPaths()
{
    return *paths;
}
```

Then I try to use a for loop to cycle through that array to find which slot does not have NULL in it. Based on that, I output certain stuff to the user:

```
string nesw[4] = {"(N)orth","(E)ast","(S)outh","(W)est"};
for(int i=0;i<=(sizeof(current->getPaths());i++)
{
    if(current[i].getPaths()!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<nesw[i].c_str()<<", ";
    }
}
```

That's where the strange stuff started to happen. Because the output of that loop was erroneous, I wrote a debug loop to see what was inside the paths array:
Consider this scenario:
I run setNearbyObjects() function to assign this data to paths array:

```
current->setNearbyObjects(NULL,objPointerA,objPointerB,NULL);
```

Then run this loop to print output to console screen:

```
for(int i=0;i<=sizeof(current->getPaths());i++)
{
    cout<<current[i].getPaths()<<endl;
}
```

The output I expected was something like this:

```
00000000
ABABABAB
007E8F28
00000000
```

But it actually was:

```
00000000
ABABABAB
007E8F28
00000001
ABABABAB
```

The length of paths array is [3], 4 slots. Why does the loop return 5 addresses? And why is the fourth address is not null, when I certainly set it to be NULL?

Comment: When the declaration is `[3]` there are only 3 slots, not 4. You're accessing outside the array, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Your debugging loop doesn't make any sense. `current` is not an array, why are you using `current[i].getPaths()`?

Comment: because... current->getPaths()[i] gives me an error. I tried it. I can't see the logic behind using current[i]->getPaths().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple assumptions here that are causing you problems.

First of all your array as it is declared only holds three elements, not four.

Second you use sizeof() on pointer `sizeof(current->getPaths())` and expect to get the array size back, what you instead get back is just the size of the pointer  in bytes. You could write a method instead that returns the number of array elements or even better use a vector to hold your pointers so when you need the size just check the size of the vector

```
std::vector<Instance*> paths;
```

...

```
paths.push_back(north);
paths.push_back(east);
paths.push_back(south);
paths.push_back(west);
```

even better is to use a vector of shared pointers `(std::shared_ptr)` in order to make the ownership clear and keep the cleanup code to a minimum

Comment: ^ok. I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it as:

```
Instance* paths[4];
```

if you want 4 elements (numbered 0 through 3).

Comment: why? E.g. in C#, if you want 4 slots, you would declare paths[3]. Why is it different here?

Comment: ok. I changed the declaration to Instance* paths[4]. Ran the loop again and... it returns 5 items still =_= Where the position of NULL pointers is not what intended.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C#. But this [array tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) doesn't show sizes in the array declarations at all.

Comment: @eltaro: You don't know what you are talking about. Arrays in `C#` are like `C` and `C++` in that the number in brackets is the number of elements and the indexes are zero-based.

Comment: This is wrong, `sizeof(current->getPaths())`. getPaths returns a pointer, the sizeof a pointer in bytes is 4, it's got nothing to do with how many elements the pointer is pointing to. Since you know there are four items in your array why not just write `for(int i=0;i<4;i++)`. Finally C++ and C# are very different. If you try to program C++ like you program C# you are going to make lots and lots of mistakes.

Comment: ^ok, now I see where I went wrong. You are right. But if I don't try to hard-code the number, how do I get the size of array?

Comment: That's why C-style arrays are poorly designed, and STL vectors were created.